# How to serialize response in string?

Tags: apex, apexrest, httpresponse

I need to set a success response in a String. How can I serialize a response in string?

Comment: Where exactly are you facing issue? Add some details in your question please.

Comment: I need to create a response json with string 'case created with caseId

Comment: Please **[edit]** your post to be more clear about observed and desired behavior, and how they diverge.

Answer (score 2):

Apex takes care of the serialization if you just return the string from your method.

From the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restresponse.htm#apex_methods_system_restresponse):

> If the method returns void, then Apex REST returns the response in the
>   responseBody property. If the method returns a value, then Apex REST
>   serializes the return value as the response.

So change your method signature to

```
@HttpPost
global static String addCases(){
 try
  {
  RestContext.response.statusCode = 200;
  return 'successfully inserted'+cases.id;
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  return 'Error:case insertion failure';
 }
}
```

You can send different status codes based on your logic.